# Why does beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler throw unexpected state exception

Tags: ios, on-demand-resources

I've received a few crash logs from users of my app regarding on-demand resources. They happen rarely and I cannot find a way to reproduce the issue.

The reason for the crash is

```
Unexpected state upon completion of beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler (3)
```

Neither I nor Google has any clue about it.

Comment: i am also getting same crash on iOS 11.4 version.

Answer (score -1):

beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler called 3 times.